# Why is Camera turning with different speed than Player with same code in different scripts? (with unity)

Tags: unity, camera, movement

I want to integrate a running character in my game, so I downloaded an animation via Mixamo. The player is running and if I attach the camera directly to the Player, it's shaking the camera and the game is not playable. Therefor I made a different script for the camera. In there, the camera is always following the player but turns (like the player) via

```
float h = PlayerMovement.horizontalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
transform.Rotate(0, h * Time.deltaTime * 60, 0);
```

(for the camera) and

```
float h = horizontalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
transform.Rotate(0, h * Time.deltaTime * 60, 0);
```

for the player. (horizontalSpeed is a constant) But after a few seconds I'm running in a completely different way then I look. Why is that and how can I solve this?

I tried different animations - nothing worked.

**Update:** If there is no rigidbody and no collider attached to it it works fine. But I need them.

Comment: Is it a 3rd person camera (ie behind the player with player in view), because here you're just rotating the camera, but to follow the players view you'd need to update the cameras position and rotation so that its behind the player and facing the same way.

Comment: As I mentioned the camera is following the player always via the camera script. And it is a first person game, so the speed and center of turning has to be the same. But because the Player is shaking, the camera is as well if I would sync the Y-Rotation-Value

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is by looking at this. But perhaps you might try LateUpdate instead of Update. Just an idea. Sorry i couldnt help more

Comment: Also, make a parent to the Player game object, then make the camera a child of that parent (and the player also a child of it)

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the player’s rotation through its rigidbody component’s [MoveRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) method. Make sure to do this in FixedUpdate.

```
void FixedUpdate() {
  float h = horizontalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
  rigidbody.MoveRotation(rigidbody.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, h * Time.deltaTime * 60, 0));
}
```

The Camera’s rotation would also need to be calculated in FixedUpdate.

Comment: Any particular reason not to use `Time.fixedDeltaTime` in `FixedUpdate`?

Comment: No reason. Inside FixedUpdate they are identical though, so the only difference is in readability

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add a movement script to the camera because if you make camera the child of player then it will follow the player without the script

Comment: As mentioned by the OP, the camera is shaking in that case, making it unplayable. (probably because it takes over all movement the player makes directly.)